# Разбить 1 массив на 2

Tags: javascript

Помогите разбить массив на 2 массива
этот:

```
p_arr=[[449,157],[202,199],[242,189],[344,134],...]
```

в эти

```
x_arr=[449,202,242,344,...]
y_arr=[157,199,189,134,...]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let initialArray = [[449,157],[202,199],[242,189],[344,134]];
let updatedInitialArray = initialArray.flat(Infinity);

let x = [];
let y = [];

updatedInitialArray.forEach((item, index) => {
  if (index % 2 === 0) {
    x.push(item);
  } else {
    y.push(item);
  }
});

console.log('x', x);
console.log('y', y);
```

```js
let initialArray = [[449,157],[202,199],[242,189],[344,134]];

let x = [];
let y = [];

initialArray.forEach(item => {
  x.push(item[0]);
  y.push(item[1]);
});

console.log('x', x);
console.log('y', y);
```

Comment: Объект не поддерживает свойство или метод "flat" у меня IE11 =(

Comment: @АлександрФелюгин, я выложил 2-а варианта решения.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю что если у меня синтаксическая ошибка => я просто могу заменить на =function() ? я просто только начал изучать)

Comment: @АлександрФелюгин, `initialArray.forEach(function(item) {...})`

Comment: ДА)) работает, спасибо тебе добрый человек! тут плюсик тебе где то можно ставить?)

Comment: @АлександрФелюгин, не за что, если ответ помог решить Вашу проблему, то слева от ответа будет галочка, нажмите на неё.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const p_arr=[[449,157],[202,199],[242,189],[344,134]];
const map = new Map(p_arr);
const [arr1,arr2] = [[...map.keys()],[...map.values()]];
console.log(arr1);
console.log(arr2);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function convert(array) {
    const result = [[], []];
    array.forEach(element => {
        result[0].push(element[0])
        result[1].push(element[1])
    })
    return result;
}

const sourceArray = [[449,157],[202,199],[242,189],[344,134]]

const [arr1, arr2] = convert(sourceArray)

console.log(arr1)
console.log(arr2)
```

Второй вариант без деструктуризации (без es6):

```js
function convert(array) {
    const result = [[], []];
    array.forEach(function(element) {
        result[0].push(element[0])
        result[1].push(element[1])
    })
    return result;
}

const sourceArray = [[449,157],[202,199],[242,189],[344,134]]

const result = convert(sourceArray)

const arr1 = result[0]
const arr2 = result[1]

console.log(arr1)
console.log(arr2)
```

Comment: Привет, второй вариант мне подошёл) спасибо большое